# Simple heat equation, solution regularity

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have a small problem with a regularity result for a simple parabolic heat equation:
Given a $C^2$ open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ called $\Omega$, and a time $T > 0$, i have the following heat equation:
$$
  y_t - \Delta y = u,\quad Q := [0,T] \times \Omega \\
  y = 0,\quad \Sigma := [0,T] \times \delta \Omega \\
  y(0) = y_0,\quad \Omega
$$
where $y_0 \in H^1(\Omega)$. Now a common result proves, that the equation has a unique solution
$$
 y \in L^\infty ( 0, T, H^1_0(\Omega)) \cap L^2(0,T,H^2(\Omega)), \\
 y_t \in L^2(0,T,L^2(\Omega)).
$$
My question now is, why the solution is also in 
$$
 H_\Sigma^{2,1} := \{ y \in L^2(0,T,H^2(\Omega)); y_t \in L^2(Q); y=0 \text{ over } \Sigma \}.
$$
The question seems pretty simple, but somehow I have a problem with the trace and the fact, that the function is only zero in the $H^1_0(\Omega)$ sense?
Thank you very much :-)

Comment: What is $Q$? Is $\Sigma = \partial \Omega$?

Comment: $Q$ and $\Sigma$ are defined as
$$
Q:=\Omega \times [0,T] \\
\Sigma := \delta \Omega \times [0,T]
$$
and $\delta \Omega$ is the boundary of $\Omega$.
Thank you

Comment: @AndreasSchmidt and Andi: it appears you have two distinct accounts. If you [visit this page and request a merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) you will be able to reliably edit your own question to provide additional clarification etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is obviously in the standard $H^1$ Sobolev space on the space-time domain $Q$:  $u \in H^{1}(Q) = \{ u : \Vert u\Vert_{L^2(Q)}^2+ \Vert \nabla u\Vert_{L^2(Q)}^2+\Vert \partial_t u \Vert_{L^2(Q)}^2 < \infty \} $ and thus the trace operation $tr|_{\Sigma} u: H^1(Q) \rightarrow L^2(\Sigma)$ is continuous. Thus the trace on $\Sigma$ is well-defined (at least in the $L^2$-sense). 
As such you can write
$$ \int_{\Sigma}  (tr|_{\Sigma}u)^2 dx = \int_{0}^T \int_{\partial \Omega} \big(tr|_{\partial \Omega}u(t)\big)(x)^2 dx dt $$
where $u(t) \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ for almost every $t \in [0,T]$. For almost every $t \in [0,T]$ you can evaluate the trace as $u(t) \in H^1(\Omega)$ and hence has to be zero.